# Tight bounds for sum of number of divisors (in a range)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logarithms, divisor-counting-function

If $d(n)$ is the number of divisors of $n$ and we consider: $S(m) =  d(1) + d(2) + .... + d(m)$, is it possible to find 2 bounds, $L$ and $U$, based on $log(m)$,   $L \le  S(m) \le U$  such that $(U - L) \le 1$ at least for $m$ larger than some $m_1$ and smaller than some larger $m_2$. And what results can I use to find by myself similar bounds ?

Comment: If such bounds exist for several consecutive numbers $m-1$  $m$, then you can use them to determine $d(m)=S(m)-S(m-1)$with an error of at most $\pm 1$, and this shoould be enough to quickly compute $d(m)$. In particular, this would  give us a fast primatlity test.

Comment: Thanks for the hint Hagen, but knowing for instance that d(m) is anything in the range [2,4] does not seem very helpful for such test for m. Or is it ?